# Get the row id that have same first name and last name

Tags: c#, .net, datarow

```
id    fname     lname     role
1     mark      anthony   lead
2     jeff      juarez    manager
3     matthew   gonzales  lead
4     mark      anthony   lead
```

i have the above table.

now i need to get the id's of all the rows that have same first name and last name.

i tried tbe below solution it is not working

```
foreach (DataRow row1 in dataTable.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataRow row2 in dataTable.Rows)
    {
           var array1 = row1.ItemArray;
           var array2 = row2.ItemArray;

           if (array1[1] == array2[1])
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Equal");
           }
           else
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Not Equal");
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RedFilter id 1 and 4 are the same.

Comment: Did you pull the contents of the dataTable from a database? If so you probably should do this in the Query and not in the code. Relational Databases are very good at this type of operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to look at both first name and last name, like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row1 in dataTable.Rows)
    foreach (DataRow row2 in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        var array1 = row1.ItemArray;
        var array2 = row2.ItemArray;

        if ((array1[1] == array2[1]) && (array1[2] == array2[2]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID#" + array1[0].ToString() + " is equal to ID#" + array2[0].ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not equal");
        }
    }
```

---

UPDATE - To remove the finding self issue change the if statement like this

```
if ((array1[0] != array2[0]) && (array1[1] == array2[1]) && (array1[2] == array2[2]))
```

Comment: yeah.. but both rows are refering to same table.. so it will be common. how to you compare first row with all rows and second row with all the rows and so on..

Comment: @srikanth I'd strongly suggest debugging through your code. IF i understand the question, and this one is (as I think it is) the right answer, just a few minutes of debugging and a strong understanding of basic conditional statements should have been enough to find the answer.

Comment: Just wondering, won't this say that "ID#1 is equal to ID#1"? If this isn't desired, it'll need to be handled.

Comment: @Hogan No problem. I would've written nested `for` loops to avoid this problem (and to avoid redundant checking also). But, what works, works.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you mean, get All ID's where the First Name = Last Name (Like "Mark Mark").

```
DataRow[] searchResults = dataTable.Select("fname = lname");
```

or, to loop

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Select("fname = lname"))
{
     //Do something cool.
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, the select method in the datatable probably does some kind of looping behind the scenes right? Either way I like this solution better.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for ROWS in the table that have the same first name and the same last name (1 and 4 in the example). Either way, the select/linq would be much better than the way the OP is going about it, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this:

```
var result = from dt in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
             group dt by new { FirstName = dt.Field<string>("FirstName"), LastName = dt.Field<string>("LastName")} into g
             where g.Count() > 1
             select dt.id;
```